# jquery click label+checkbox detect which?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check the event.target.nodeName as follows:

```
$("input").click(function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName == "LABEL") {
       alert('label click');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
       alert($(this).attr('checked') ? 'checked': 'unchecked');
    }
});
```

But the name never equals label? What am I doing wrong?

Quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TDvcV/)

Comment: In this scenario `nodeName` will always be equal to the element you selected for the event. There's no way to attach to the label unless you select the label initially.

Comment: Always bind the container element if you thinking of using `e.target`, basically the handler is executed as the event bubbled all the way down to the child element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should select the `label`(*parent*) element. Currently the only target of your click handler is the input element:

```
$("label").click(function(e){
  // ...
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j7nSq/

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason this doesn't work is because this will only run if you click on input:

```
  if(e.target.nodeName == "LABEL") {
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not selecting the label at all. Select the label first and try again:

You are hitting the wrong element here..

```
$('label').on('click', function(e) {
    // Your logic here

});
```

Instead of click on input.

Make sure you delegate the event using `.on()`.

Comment: Nitpick: your example uses `on()`, but it's not delegating.

Comment: I'm not even sure I'm correct anymore (since your code does handle clicks bubbled from the input), but usually when I see the term "delegation" it refers to cases when you target descendant nodes, but the handler is attached to the parent (like in `$('label').on('click', 'input', function ...`, which wouldn't solve the OP problem here). So forget what I said, I'm not sure if that's technically delegation or not.

Comment: @bfavaretto.. Think I used the wrong workd here.. Looks like you are right :)